# How to prevent Windows 7 from asking during file copy/backup

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

I use Windows's built in copy (drap and drop) to backup files (thousands of them in many folders up to 3 levels deep). I want to keep old files untouched but only update new files.

But Windows has the bad habit of asking me questions like "do you want to overwrite folders" or "do you want to replace, keep both or do not copy". I don't mind answering the question but it always ask in the middle of copy which is around half an hour for me and both questions are not asked back-to-back. It is like: Copy, (30 min later), Q1, (10 min later), Q2, etc.

Is there a way to default Windows' copy behavior to "always copy new files and update folders"?

Comment: You won't be able to use Windows Explorer, and have it remember your choice, its design specifically calls for user confirmation on all conflicts.  Each folder, is considered to have its own conflicts, best way around that is to use third-party software to sync changes between folders.

Comment: Maybe you can search for a registry value for it. (Try to search online). Which corresponds with the prompt dialog box.

Comment: Or you can forget about doing backups with windows explorer and use [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/). It will do exactly what you want - synchronize files and folders according to your preferences without asking questions :)